# PowerBI having issue with Access DB having ODBC Connection

Tags: powerbi

I have an accessDB which using ODBC connection to SQL and used in queries. 
Tried to use the queries to create a report on PowerBi, Issue is whenever I tried to update the dataset it gives me  ODBC--call failed.

Tried created the ODBC connection on gateway machine. they are all 32 bit [ODBC/Power Bi Desktop] etc.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

had to install office 64bit and access 64bit driver
also had to refresh all the linked tables and views from access to rectify the issue.